# How to add dSPACE AutomationDesk libraries to Python interpreter?

Tags: python, environment, dspace-ecu

I want to create virtual enviornment with access to dSAPCE AutomationDesk libraries such as reportlibrary, mainlibrary, evaluation, rtplib2, rs232lib2, matlablib2, ..

1. I have installed dSPACE ControlDesk 5.6, dSPACE AutomationDesk 5.2and dSPACE Python Extensions 2.1 on local computer.
2. I have found Python Interpreter installed by dSPACE installator (it includes additional dSPACE libraries under path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\Lib\site-packages\dSPACECommon')
3. Then I have added to sys.path following paths:
   'C:\Program Files (x86)\dSPACE AutomationDesk 5.2\Main\bin'
   'C:\Program Files (x86)\dSPACE AutomationDesk 5.2\Main\DSPythonModules\AutomationDeskPackages\*' (all folders located here)

   Is it possible to somehow configure these libraries in my Python environment? Or should I create some stubs manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I have learned and find out, there is not possible to create virtual enviroment for AutomationDesk without making some stubs (manually?).
AutomationDesk python libraries have references to AutomationDesk build-in libraries (which are files in non-python format) and therefore the problem is more complex and requires out of the box solution.